# PhoneGap 3/ Cordova 3 does not open up e-mail links (mailto) with the native mail application (ios)

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, mailto

I updated a phonegap 2.5 app to ios7 and cordova 3.1. It runs only on iOS.

When the external links wouldn't open, I included the InAppBrowser plugin and that worked.

But how to I get the mail links (E-Mail me) to open in the native mail program? There is no such plugin.

I tried the contacts plugin. But it wasn't that.

I saw the [EMail Composer plugin](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/EmailComposer), but I am looking for support by cordova or a cordova plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just solved it.

Seems to be a missing feature of the iOS simulator. On my iPhone 4 it works.

Answer (score 2):

I used this simple html style of doing it. Works fine on ios7 and cordova 3.5 and android 4.4

```
<a href="mailto:abc@gmail.com" data-rel='external'>
```

I'm not even using any plugins such as inappbrowser, just in case you have that doubt.